# Where to find Uniswap contract addresses on Goerli testnet

Tags: ethers.js, uniswap, ethereumjs, goerli

I am attempting to create a nodejs arbitrage bot. I can get my bot to fetch pairs from the mainnet but cannot fetch Uniswap pairs using the Goerli testnet.

For example, on the mainnet to get the WETH/WBTC pair I use:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.InfuraProvider('mainnet', process.env.INFURA_KEY);

const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

const uniswapFactory = new ethers.Contract(
  '0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f',
  UniswapV2Factory.abi, wallet,
);

const wethAddress = '0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2';
const wbtcAddress = '0x2260fac5e5542a773aa44fbcfedf7c193bc2c599'


const wbtcPairContract = new ethers.Contract(
  uniswapFactory.getPair(wethAddress, wbtcAddress),
  UniswapV2Pair.abi, wallet,
);
```

And I get the wbtc address from https://etherscan.io/address/0x2260fac5e5542a773aa44fbcfedf7c193bc2c599

However, if I try and use the Goerli testnet I use https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f for my Uniswap factory contract, https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xb4fbf271143f4fbf7b91a5ded31805e42b2208d6 for my WETH & https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xe6d830937fa8db2ebd2c046c58f797a95550fa4e for my wbtc.

When trying to get the pair for the above I get:

```
Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getReserves()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.6.4)
    at Logger.makeError (/Users/random/GolandProjects/random/uni-sushi-flashloaner/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:233:21)
    at Logger.throwError (/Users/random/GolandProjects/random/uni-sushi-flashloaner/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:242:20)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (/Users/random/GolandProjects/random/uni-sushi-flashloaner/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/interface.js:388:23)
    at Contract.<anonymous> (/Users/random/GolandProjects/random/uni-sushi-flashloaner/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:395:56)
    at step (/Users/random/GolandProjects/random/uni-sushi-flashloaner/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/random/GolandProjects/random/uni-sushi-flashloaner/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (/Users/random/GolandProjects/roger/uni-sushi-flashloaner/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:20:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  reason: null,
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  method: 'getReserves()',
  data: '0x',
  errorArgs: null,
  errorName: null,
  errorSignature: null,
  address: Promise { '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000' },
  args: [],
  transaction: {
    data: '0x0902f1ac',
    to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    from: '0x4Aec689A464ba3676Eb04ec1c7278819CB9B8521'
  }
}
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Or is there a list of contract addresses to use on the testnets for testing Uniswap?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe that specific pair simply doesnt exist?

Comment: @Foxxxey is there a way to find pairs on the testnet?

Comment: did you get an answer that works? I don't get it.

Answer (score 6):

Just set your wallet for goerli network, go to app.uniswap.org, click "Pool" and "+ New Position" - then you can see the available tokens - I see ETH, UNI and WETH and you can 'Manage Token Lists' at the bottom of "select a token".

I created a UNI/WETH position to play with. Using addresses from the deployments reference https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/deployments  I can query for that pool at https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984#readContract

2. getPool
   0x1f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984    <-- UNI token and UniswapV3Factory 
   0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6    <-- WETH token
   3000                <-- fee ?

returns the pool:
const poolAddress = '0x4d1892f15B03db24b55E73F9801826a56d6f0755';

Comment: is there no list of the addresses of the tokens? I don't get it, why do I have first to do a transaction?

Answer (score 5):

the. Uniswap contract address on Goerli is `0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984`.

To find a token address on Goerli, you most go https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap, connect you wallet on Goerli network does a transaction with token that you get to choose, after transaction success you can get contract address on Goerli.
[image]

Comment: for future reference you can find all the deployed contract addresses on the uniswap documentation page as well: https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/deployments

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the answer got handled. If you do need more Goerli testETH - https://goerlifaucet.com/ is Alchemy's faucet that's really reliable.